# Java Char Array To Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Looking for a way to convert String to a map of "char" => int (index of). Obviously this assumes String has unique characters.

Is there a way to do it with Streams? I thought this would work but am  running into errors trying to compile it:

```
String alphabet = "0123456789";
alphabet.chars().collect(Collectors.toMap(alphabet::charAt, Function.identity()));
```

Basically I want something equivalent to the Python code:

```
{c, i for i,c in enumerate("0123456789")}
```

Comment: What happens for duplicates in the input, like "bee"? What should `'e'` map to?

Comment: Beware that `Map<Character, Integer>` is a very expensive data structure due to *boxing*. Do not use it in performance critical code. Consider e.g. goldman sachs collections instead (though conversion will be more expensive). `enumerate` in Python isn't cheaper either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This creates a map from each character to its integer:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length())
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(alphabet::charAt, Function.identity()));
```

Note that it won't work if you have repeated characters.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. Any idea why it won't work without the call to .boxed()?

Comment: Because `IntStream#collect` takes in 3 arguments (`Supplier<R> supplier, ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner`), and you need to use .boxed() to convert it to a `Stream<T>` which can accept `Collector`s.

Comment: Note also that `boxed()` is simply shorthand for `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`;

Answer (score 6):

This works.

```
Map<Integer, Character> map =
  IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length()).boxed()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, alphabet::charAt));
```

edit:

of course if you used Scala instead (also runs on the JVM) you could write it much shorter. Then it would just be `alphabet.zipWithIndex.toMap`

Comment: This is pretty elegant, but elaborating a bit more on why it works the way it does would make it really complete.

Comment: Thanks. The .boxed() call is what I was missing.

Just for clarification I wanted a Map<Character, Integer> but yours is pretty much what I want so I accepted.

Comment: As with most Java related questions, this can be answered by looking at the API documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ . An IntStream object doesn't have the type of collect method you need. boxed() converts it to a normal Stream.

Comment: Note that boxed streams are even more expensive; but if you want to build a boxed map, you'll have to pay that price eventually.

Answer (score 6):

You asked in comments how to do it with 3-argument `IntStream#collect`.  Here it is:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length())
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m, i) -> m.put(alphabet.charAt(i), i), Map::putAll);
```

If you want to do duplicate check like `toMap` does and still use the 3-argument form, you will have to update **both** 2nd (accumulator) and 3rd (combiner) arguments to do the check:

```
map = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length())
    .collect(
        HashMap::new, 
        (m, i) -> m.merge(alphabet.charAt(i), i, 
            (a,b) -> {throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate!");}
        ), 
        (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((c,i) -> 
            m1.merge(c, i, (a,b) -> {throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate!");})
        )
    );
```

As you see, this gets ugly and you would probably want to define a helper method to simplify this.  If you are willing to disallow parallel stream, you can get away with only checking for duplicates in accumulator but then you will have to have the combiner throw an exception:

```
map = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length())
    .collect(
            HashMap::new, 
            (m, i) -> m.merge(alphabet.charAt(i), i, 
                (a,b) -> {throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate!");}
            ), 
            (m1, m2) -> {throw new AssertionError("parallel not allowed");}
);
```

Unless you are doing this as an exercise, it's better to just leave all this mess for `toMap` to deal with.  That's what it's there for.

Comment: I'm trying to work it out now. The only difference is using boxed and then to toMap() enforces unique key constraint, yours won't throw an IllegalStateException on duplicate. Thanks though.

Comment: Logic for duplicates just means turning the (m, i) into an expression and checking for duplicates though, you put me on the right track. Thanks again!

Comment: @aamit915 be careful how you do it.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Quick question, since I'm still pretty new to lambdas: why does `Map::putAll` work? I would've used `(m1,m2) -> m1.putAll(m2)` since `putAll` accepts a `Map`, it's an instance method, and the argument lengths of `putAll` and `accept` are different.

Comment: @TNT `Map::putAll` is a method reference that's equivalent to `(m1,m2) -> m1.putAll(m2)`.  Take a look at JLS for all the possible method reference expressions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13

Comment: Interesting. I learn something new every day. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Given the type of input in the question, not using the `alphabet` string at all, will make checking for duplicates obsolete: `IntStream.rangeClosed('0', '9') .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i)->m.put((char)i, i-'0'), Map::putAll)`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the various solutions posted here, `stream()` doesn't make things a whole lot easier.

While functional-style spaghetti code is all the rage right now, I suggest to use **imperative programming** for readability.

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) map.put(s.charAt(i), i);
```

Seriously, **procedural can be much nicer sometimes**! People underappreciate the clarity of procedural code, and it's efficiency.

However, you probably want to use this code instead for your scenario:

```
if (c<'0' || c>'9') throw RuntimeException("Not a digit");
int digit = c - '0';
```

which is *much* cheaper (faster, and 0 memory) than a `Map`.